# Mixed content - Some radio streams are blocked and some are warned about but allowed - Why?

Tags: stream, warnings, internet-radio, mixed-content, blocked

I have made a radio player page on my website at https://jacobsm.com/mjrandradio.htm and I am loading it under Windows 10 with the browser Edge Version 113.0.1774.57 (Official build) (64-bit).

Some stations do not play, because the browser blocks them being loaded under an https page. However, they will stream correctly in a new window of their own.
For example http://46.105.124.120:8604/stream

Some stations play, with a warning rather than a block in the browser console. For example http://stream.radioreklama.bg/veronika.ogg or http://airprogressive.org:8000/stream

My question is why do certain streams only warn and others are blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason turns out to be because using a dotted IP address in the URL makes the browser block the mixed content, whereas a qualified URL only warns about the mixed content but lets it play.